# Output written to stdout via forked processes

Tags: c, linux

I have a process that forks, performs computation and writes out data to stdout. The child process also writes out data to stdout after performing some computation. Currently, the output from the parent and the child come out separately. However, I'm concerned that the output from the child may be printed mixed with the output from the parent.

I.e. I have this line in both the child and the process :-

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", do_computation());
```

Is there any neat way to prevent the writes from being interleaved? It hasn't happened so far, however I'm concerned that it may.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard multitasking issue, and is solved the same way any other shared resource is protected: it's your responsibility to create and manage semaphores so the processes can negotiate periods of exclusive access to shared resources such as these streams, or to arrange similarly safe mechanisms for them to communicate amongst themselves (eg having the child processes respond not to stdout but via a pipe per process back to the parent, and having the parent poll those pipes and report their results as complete messages become available).

There should be plenty of good tutorials on the web on multiprocess programming in C.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, you want to achieve before-or-after atomicity for the fprintf calls in different process. You can in the parent process, waitpid for the child process right before the fprintf call so that the call in parent process is guaranteed to be executed after the child terminates without reducing the parallelism of the computation.